# Black Login Window & Ubuntu Logo Disappeared - 11.10 with Gnome 3

Tags: login, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

10 on my Compaq Laptop with nvidia on board graohics.

The History
Since I dont like unity, I have installed Gnome 3 on top of it. I was updating daily and was having a good time with my ubuntu (was getting relieved from most of the linux bugs which used to irritate me long back).

I have installed some shell extensions and last day I read about Linux Mint extensions and installed MGSE using the info here.
http://maketecheasier.com/use-linux-mint-mgse-in-ubuntu/2011/11/22

It was working find, but during an update happened two day's before, I got a prompt to confirm replacing my Grub (not very sure what it was) or something like that.I went ahead since it was an update.

The Issue
After this update,while booting, the background from the grub menu to the login page has becomeblack. There is no background at all and I am getting a black login page. I am able to login from there and everything looks fine after that. Also, the ubuntu logo during booting is not at all getting displayed and it just shows a black empty screen there.

I am very sad becasue of this and I removed all the mint MGSE extensions and everything hoping this will comeback. But the screen is still black. Please help me. I am pretty new to the technical side of linux and wont understand big technical language. Thanks for your patience.